# When Authorization header is present in the request, its' always a Cache Miss

Tags: caching, apache-traffic-server

When Authorization header present in the inbound request, it's always a Cache Miss. My requirement is, I need ATS to treat the `Authorization` header like any other header (It should not cause cache miss and it should get forwarded to upstream service). How can I achieve this.

This may sound non-secure, but, I have a specific usecase for this. This cache is for internal use and it's access is controlled by other means.

I tried this

As per the [official documentation](https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/admin-guide/configuration/cache-basics.en.html#client-directives)

> By default, Traffic Server does not cache objects with the following
>   request headers:
>
> Authorization
>
> Cache-Control: no-store
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> To configure Traffic Server to ignore this request header,
>
> Edit proxy.config.http.cache.ignore_client_no_cache in records.config.
>
> CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.ignore_client_no_cache INT 1 Run the
>   command traffic_ctl config reload to apply the configuration changes.

but, no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/admin-guide/configuration/cache-basics.en.html#configuring-traffic-server-to-ignore-www-authenticate-headers did the trick for me.

The following instructions was applicable for `Authorization` header as well, besides `WWW-Authenticate` Header. They need to update the documentation.

## Configuring Traffic Server to Ignore WWW-Authenticate Headers

By default, Traffic Server does not cache objects that contain WWW-Authenticate response headers. The WWW-Authenticate header contains authentication parameters the client uses when preparing the authentication challenge response to an origin server.

When you configure Traffic Server to ignore origin server `WWW-Authenticate` headers, all objects with `WWW-Authenticate` headers are stored in the cache for future requests. However, the default behavior of not caching objects with `WWW-Authenticate` headers is appropriate in most cases. Only configure Traffic Server to ignore server `WWW-Authenticate` headers if you are knowledgeable about HTTP 1.1.

To configure Traffic Server to ignore server `WWW-Authenticate` headers:

Edit `proxy.config.http.cache.ignore_authentication` in `records.config`.

```
CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.ignore_authentication INT 1
```

Run the command `traffic_ctl config reload` to apply the configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

If your origin returns a cache-control header with the 'public' directive (for instance, "Cache-Control: max-age=60,public") or including the s-maxage directive (for instance, "Cache-Control: s-maxage=60"), ATS should start caching the object. The relevant http RFC:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.8

> ```
> When a shared cache (see section 13.7) receives a request
> ```

```
  containing an Authorization field, it MUST NOT return the
  corresponding response as a reply to any other request, unless one
  of the following specific exceptions holds:
  1. If the response includes the "s-maxage" cache-control
     directive, the cache MAY use that response
```

...
3. If the response includes the "public" cache-control directive,
it MAY be returned in reply to any subsequent request.

Similarly, you could also use the header_rewrite plugin to remove the Authorization header from the request, or to add public/s-maxage.